# What is the simplest way to display a graphics drawing in Java AWT?

Tags: java, awt, frame

I want to use a parent class, preferably Component (being the highest up AWT gui class I'm aware of). I'm not a newbie to programming but I am self taught and am having problems getting example code for my question. Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
public class DrawSquare extends Frame{
    public DrawSquare(){
        setBounds(0,0,100,100);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        new DrawSquare();
    }
}
```

Basically I want to do the same thing with a parent class to 'possibly' have quicker and more efficient code. I'm assuming that Frame has more in built options such as a border while Window (a parent class) does not, but I have only been able to make this simple code with Frame.

I want to use AWT, not swing btw.

Comment: I;m not understanding the question  - but you dont have a graphics to begin with where is it?

Comment: this program makes a square 100x100 in the corner of the screen by extending Frame. Extending anything else, it won't be displayed.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid Swing, anyway?  All the current documentation (like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)) is for Swing and it doesn’t cost you anything to use it.

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests:

```
class C extends Component {
  public C() { setSize(200, 200); setVisible(true); }
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

will not be displayed because presumably it needs something to be added to.

```
class C extends Container {
  public C() { setSize(200, 200); setVisible(true); }
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

will not be displayed because it is a container so it needs other things to be added to it.

```
class C2 extends Window {
  public C2() { super(new Frame()); setLocation(100, 100); setSize(200, 200); setVisible(true);  }
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

can be displayed but has nothing to grab around and it even doesn't show on the task bar so its a useless thing unless you add it somewhere.

So

```
class C extends Frame {
  public C() { setSize(200, 200); setVisible(true);  }
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

is your solution as the first that is both a Component and a Container.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I was looking for. I couldn't figure out how to get a Window to work because I didn't use the keyword super, I had been doing this: public C(Window owner){}. Now I have window as an option but seems just as complex. I was fiddling around with Canvas but couldn't get that to display either. I had already kind of figured the reasons you specified for why Component and Container wouldn't show.

Comment: Every one of those overridden paint methods should call the super method first. The 'simplest' approach is not always robust.